# How to design UIs that are screen independent?

Tags: android, android-layout

I make use of Linear Layouts and then add weights to the layout to make the layouts screen independent. It solves the problem but I've been told that this approach is not preferable?

How do I solve this major issue?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you have a look on the PercentRelativeLayout

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html

it's a small extension of RelativeLayout in which you can use Percentage as width and height 
for example (taken from documentation)

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <ImageView
     app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
     app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
     app:layout_marginTopPercent="25%"
     app:layout_marginLeftPercent="25%"/>
```

now that would be different on different screen according to screen width and height

you could also check out Snake comment below which I guess is more promising

**Update**
As @cricket_007 pointed out the PercentRelativeLayout was deprecated in API level 26.0.0-beta1.So you should really use ConstraintLayout you could still check the link above to reach the same result with ConstraintLayout.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use Constraint Layout which is the "upgraded model" of relative layout?

Comment: yeah sure constraint layout are optimize and flatten the view hierarchy which is better but I haven't really used it yet so I didn't want to give my opinion about it till I implement it and see thee performance for myself :)

Comment: You do have a point about the percentage as it seems easier with the relative parent. I am going to post a question to the community about the comparison

Comment: should be interesting :D

Comment: Well... **This class was deprecated in API level 26.0.0-beta1.**
  *consider using ConstraintLayout and associated layouts instead*

Comment: Well I guess that solve the riddle in the end, thank you @cricket_007 I'm going to edit the answer

Comment: @cricket_007 that's crazy. How come they deprecate something new they added. Look how big the xml needed to make one button stretch in Contraint layout

Comment: @Snake Just because it is deprecated doesn't mean it should be avoided or not used. Android team probably released it while in the middle of making ConstraintLayout library as a temporary solution

Comment: @Snake sad but true I guess it's more or less the xml is going into the direction of iOS storyboard constrains